# Spacing prior to start of the nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature

I am using the nomencl package and trying to remove the spacing between the start of the page and the "Nomenclature" title. `\vspace{...}` does not achieve the desired effect, so I assume this must be done through the `nomencl` pacakge. I have read the documentation and searched these forums, but I have not found any question addressing this problem. Can you help me fix my code?

Below is a small working example, modulo the spacing problem I have just described.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

Title

\nomenclature{GMRES}{Generalised method of residuals}
\nomenclature{RMSE}{Root mean squared error}
\nomenclature{PDE}{Partial differential equation}
\nomenclature{SPDE}{Stochastic partial differential equation}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

I am compiling using the following sequence of commands:

```
pdflatex ${filename}.tex
makeindex ${filename}.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o ${filename}.nls
pdflatex ${filename}.tex
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Good MWE for a first question. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do it: the nomenclature is a chapter that should receive the same treatment as all the others.

Anyway, you have to neutralize the 50pt vertical space that `report` puts above chapter titles.

Here's a clean way to do it: when the `thenomenclature` environment is started, we patch `\@makeschapterhead` to remove the `\vspace{50\p@}` instruction.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the alignment

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{thenomenclature}{%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

Title

\nomenclature{GMRES}{Generalised method of residuals}
\nomenclature{RMSE}{Root mean squared error}
\nomenclature{PDE}{Partial differential equation}
\nomenclature{SPDE}{Stochastic partial differential equation}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

The `arara` directives are just for being able to compile the whole thing without hassles. The `showframe` package is for showing the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am moving the Nomenclature title up to comply with the chapters. For some reason it is not affected by the page style I set through fancyhdr, hence my question.

Your example works fine, but when I compile my main document with your additions the position remains unchanged. I suspect that fancyhdr interferes with your patch, but I simply guessing at this point.

Comment: @stephn28 `fancyhdr` has nothing to do with typesetting of chapter titles.