# Remove Space Above Nomenclature Title in Article Class

Tags: spacing, article, nomenclature, vertical

I am using article document class and I am making all my section titles appearing centred at top of page. I am making a separate page for the nomenclature using `\usepackage{nomencl}` and everything is wokring fine EXCEPT: I would like the 'Nomenclature' title to appear centered at the top of the page and the list of symbols begin underneath with a space between title and first entry of, lets say 1cm.

I have checked some similar questions, but they appear to be using book or report class, which I think has something to do with why those solutions won't work in my case:

[Remove space before nomenclature in Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345620/remove-space-before-nomenclature-in-lyx)

and

[Spacing prior to start of the nomenclature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233707/spacing-prior-to-start-of-the-nomenclature)

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind linking the answers that do not work for you to your question?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a real document, you probably want `\printnomenclature` to be preceded by text and, possibly, by `\clearpage` so that it starts at the top.

If the document has just nomenclature, you need `\mbox{}` so a page is actually shipped out and the nomenclature entries are written out.

In this case, add `\mbox{}` *after* `\printnomenclature`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature

\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

Note: the image has been prepared with `\usepackage{showframe}` in order to show the page boundaries.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put the below code at the preamble of your main LaTeX document.

```
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\vspace*{-1cm}}
```

I hope this helps!